# No funciona el dropdown boostrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap, dropdown

Tengo un problema con Bootstrap ya que al hacer un dropdown button no se desplega envió codigo

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!---BOOTSTRAP--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!---FONT AWESOME--->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e992ae22f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!---AJAX--->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>BonosyPuntos.com</title>
</head>

        <!---BOOTSTRAP--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Productos</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosC" class="dropdown-item">Crear Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosT" class="dropdown-item">Todos Los Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosCo"  class="dropdown-item">Comprados</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: O bien no has cargado los scripts de bootstrap de la versión 5.x o bien estás usando bootstrap 4.x o inferior.  Aqui con bootstrap 5 funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/4orh8a3d/

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con los script que pongo e uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te funciona porque estás cargando dos veces el javascript de bootstrap.

En esta linea cargas el completo (que tambien contiene popper):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

y dos líneas más abajo estas cargando el normal (sin popper):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Si eliminas el de arriba te funcionará, pues luego cargas el popper y el normal.  Pero si eliminas el de abajo del todo mejor que borres tambien el popper porque va incluido en el bundle. Léete bien [la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Ejemplo:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!---BOOTSTRAP--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!---FONT AWESOME--->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e992ae22f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!---AJAX--->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>BonosyPuntos.com</title>
</head>

        <!---BOOTSTRAP--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Productos</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosC" class="dropdown-item">Crear Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosT" class="dropdown-item">Todos Los Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=productosCo"  class="dropdown-item">Comprados</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```